# replace NA by truncated normal distribution values in r

Tags: r, na

I am trying to replace NAs by truncated normal distribution values. 
First I used `sample` as follows and the function worked:

```
  v.new <- replace(vector,v, sample(8,length(v),replace =FALSE))
```

However when I try to use `rtnorm` it seems  not to work. I got any error messages and it takes ages to replace the NAs by the desired interval. Any suggestion to make this work?

```
library(msm)

# Some data 
data("airquality")
airquality$Ozone

# My function
add.trunc.to.NAvector <- function(vector){
v <- NULL
for(i in 1:length(vector)){
if(is.na(vector[i])==TRUE)
  v <- append(v, i)
}
mean.val <- mean(vector)
sd.val <- sd(vector)
min.val <- mean.val - 4 * sd.val
max.val <- mean.val + 4 * sd.val 
v.new <- replace(vector,v, rtnorm(length(v), lower = min.val, upper = max.val))


return(v.new)
}
```

Comment: Couldn't you just do `replace(vector, vector[is.na(vector)], rtnorm(...))`? What is not working? What is not working? What is the expected result?

Comment: It takes long time to run without a result and I do not get any error message.

Comment: Please add more information to your question. What packages are you using? What is `vector` (probably `airquality$Ozone`, but specify to make things unambiguous)? What is expected result?

Comment: What I expect as a result is to replace all the NA by values ranging from  `min.val` and `max.val`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Should not this work?

```
v <- airquality$Ozone
v.new <- v
indices <- which(is.na(v))
m <- mean(v[-indices])
s <- sd(v[-indices])
v.new[indices] <- rtnorm(length(indices), lower = m-4*s, upper = m+4*s)
```